# adding MySQL column to a table using trigger

Tags: mysql, variables, triggers, addition, dynamic-columns

I have a table that looks like this:

**Counters:**

| *client_id*  | *provider1*   |   *provider2*   |   *provider3* |

_ - _ - _- _ - _ - _- _ - _ - _

the column names `[provider1,provider2,...]` is the id of provider which is stored in another table called "providers".

what i need is, when a new provider is inserted into the "proviers" database a trigger would automatically add another column in the "Counters" table, but I can't seem to be able to get it.

---

this is what i have so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `providers_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `providers` FOR EACH ROW
    ALTER TABLE `counters` ADD NEW.prov_id int;
```

the error is at the '.' between 'NEW; and 'prov_id' with the error:

```
Syntax error: unexpected '.' (dot)
```

I am guessing it needs a string value as the name of the column so i searched around and found a way to pass it as a string:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `providers_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `providers` FOR EACH ROW
    ALTER TABLE `counters` ADD CAST(NEW.prov_id AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8) int;
```

but this shows me an error at the 'ADD' saying it is unexpected.

also tried surrounding the variable with brackets `{NEW.prov_id}` but to no avail, it gives the same error at the 'ADD' clause.

also, while searching I also in some posts that says it does not work while some say it does work, and those who say it works don't use a variable for the column name.

how can i fix this error? and is it even doable?

my MySQL is v5.0
I can upgrade it, if necessary.

Thank you in advnace

Comment: I doubt there is any way short of using a stored procedure to do all your inserts, and having it `PREPARE` dynamic queries (and even then, I am not sure dynamic queries support DDL statements). Even if you found a way, I would recommend against it; even having such columns is considered bad database design, let alone automating their creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Impossible.

ALTER TABLE is a so-called "DDL-statement" (data definition language), which differs from "DML-statements" (data manipulation language).

DDL-Statements are not allowed in triggers, afaik.

You would need dynamic SQL to do this, because table names are not variable in DDL.

Unfortunately, dynamic SQL is not allowed in triggers. When trying to execute a prepare statement in a trigger, mysql throws an error:

```
Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger
```

More in the mysql documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html

Comment: Is there another way of doing this? can use a stored procedure? is there a way around it? i need something.. we can alter tables using SQL so there must be a way around this?

Comment: I am sure I can do this in my script which would execute the insert first and execute another query for altering, but I need it to be handled by the DBMS rather than the connecting end (my script)

Comment: try to avoid the NEW.prov_id. Just try alter table <tablename> add column <colname> <type>. Don't use the new-keyword at all.

Maybe that works out

Comment: Column name is unknown, it depends on the insert which defines which column would be updated