# MySQL trigger update dynamic column

Tags: mysql, triggers, dynamic-columns

I have a table that i need to update every time something is inserted in another table.

table to be updated: `counters` on insert in `sales`.
the problem is the column that will be updated in `counters` differs based on the insert in the table `sales`.

I have been looking around and searching since yesterday, but to no avail.
i tried using the `CAST(.. AS CHAR)` function but to no avail.

this is what the statement should look like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `sales_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `sales` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE counters SET {NEW.sale_provider} = {NEW.sale_provider} + NEW.sale_quantity WHERE counters.cnt_sendername = NEW.sale_sendername;
END;
```

where the `{New.sale_provider}` is the name of the column to be updated.

counter table looks like:

| *sendername* | *prov1* | *prov2* | *prov3* | ...

Where column names (prov1,prov2..) are the id of the providers

Is this possible? how can I do this?
I am new to triggers and still lack the deeper understanding of SQL language and MySQL's capabilities.

## Notes:

- There are 4 columns as a start since there are 4 providers, the counter table serves a quick access to limits instead of calculating it every time, this will be used quite a lot and recalculating it every time is very resources consuming.
- With every new provider added a new column will be added to the counter table, it should be updateable as well, thus some form of a variable is needed.

your help is most appreciated!

## EDIT:

The point is that the updated column will be different every time, I know this is unconventional but i believe it is doable non the less.
The new data inserted into `sales` will affect a column in `counter`, but which column it will effect is what needs to be determined.

After looking for a while i found something which can solve what i need, but still can't get it to run:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `sales_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `sales` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET colname= New.sale_provider;
    UPDATE counters SET colname = colname + NEW.sale_quantity WHERE counters.cnt_sendername = NEW.sale_sendername;
END;
```

but it tells me that `colname` is not a system variable?
I have been searching for how to assign a variable and they all look like what i did, what is wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding MySQL column to a table using trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42450231/adding-mysql-column-to-a-table-using-trigger)

Comment: @Psi that is altering a table where a new column is inserted, this is updating an existing column which it's name is variable - completely different.

Comment: Same answer: dynamic SQL not allowed in triggers. column names are not variable in DDL, same as table names

Comment: @Psi even dynamic SQL is not allowed? so there is no way of doing something like this inside the MySQL DBMS? is it possible to update an external static column from within a trigger? i.e. `UPDATE table SET column = NEW.val WHERE id = NEW.id AND name = NEW.name` ?

Comment: This is allowed, because there is no dynamic SQL involved. Dynamic SQL means: create a new sql statement from a string you created in the trigger/stored function/procedure to create queries based upon dynamic values. In this case, you just use a well defined statement right from the beginning and you just use DML instead of DDL.

Comment: @Psi well this was a let down, I got over excited with triggers. thank you for clearing that up, your help was most appreciated. You learn something everyday.

Comment: Maybe you change your data structure to a key/value based approach: Read about Entity Attribute Value. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want with a single update, using a condition on each column:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `sales_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `sales` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE counters c
        SET prov1 = c.prov1  + (case when NEW.sale_provider = 'prov1' THEN NEW.sale_quantity else 0 end),
            prov2 = c.prov2  + (case when NEW.sale_provider = 'prov2' THEN NEW.sale_quantity else 0 end),
            prov3 = c.prov3  + (case when NEW.sale_provider = 'prov3' THEN NEW.sale_quantity else 0 end),
            prov4 = c.prov4 + (case when NEW.sale_provider = 'prov4' THEN NEW.sale_quantity else 0 end)         
        WHERE c.cnt_sendername = NEW.sale_sendername;
END;
```

I would also recommend that you change the table to have one row per provider.  That way, you don't have to change the trigger to add new providers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `sales_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `sales` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE counters c
        SET quantity = c.quantity  + NEW.sale_quantity
        WHERE c.cnt_sendername = NEW.sale_sendername AND
              c.provider = NEW.sale_provider
END;
```

This makes querying the table as a cross-tab a little bit harder, but that is not a big deal.

Both of these assume that `counters` is pre-initialized with all the rows it needs.  This is probably not reasonable.  So, you should create a unique index on `sales_after_insert(cnt_sendername, provider)` and use `insert on duplicate key`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `sales_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `sales` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO counters(cnt_sendername, provider, quantity)
         VALUES (NEW.sale_sendername, NEW.sale_provider, NEW.sale_quantity)
         ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = quantity + VALUES(quantity);
END;
```

Comment: This means i have to list all the providers, this makes it static. if a new provider is added i would have to manually add that condition to the trigger, I need it to be dynamic

Comment: @bakz . . . Then you have the wrong data structure.

Comment: I am not that experienced with databases, but I know the way i structured this is not a conventional way, but I know what I need yet I am failing to convey my point, is it possible to set the table's name as a variable much like in PHP? I think MySQL supports variables